# How to understand the np.argwhere function?

Tags: numpy

```
Signature: np.argwhere(a)
Docstring:
Find the indices of array elements that are non-zero, grouped by element.
```

### Examples

```
>>> x = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
>>> x
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
>>> np.argwhere(x>1)
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2]])
```

What does it mean by 'non-zero' and 'grouped by element'? and what is "x>1"?

Comment: Any guesses on what `x>1` might be?

Comment: x is a 2-d array. 'x>1' means each element >1?

Comment: `argwhere` is the transpose of `where`.  Generally `np.where` is more useful.  Look at its results.

Comment: You should read up on [`boolean-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the indices *(positions)* of array elements that are non-zero *(true)*, grouped by element *(each index is its own row)*.

Basically, if you pass a boolean array, you will find the indices where that array is true, but transposed so that the indices in the form `[[x1, x2, ...], [y1, y2, ...]]` become in the form `[[x1, y1], [x2, y2], ...]`.

`x > 1` is a boolean array which is `True` wherever `x > 1` and `False` wherever `x <= 1`. In your example, it looks loke

```
[[False, False, True],
 [True,  True,  True]]
```

Comment: It's still not clear to me for the part of "grouped by element". For example, how does [0, 2] come?

Comment: Means that on row 0 from the original matrix, the index 2 has a number that satisfies `x>1`. If you try `x[0][2]>1` it should be `true`

Answer (score 4):

In each row the first entry is the row index and the second entry is the column index of the entries of x that satisfy the condition.

For example:
2 is greater than 1
so the first row of argwhere gives you `[0, 2]`
pointing to the position of 2 in x.